# Print formatting in python3 - how to get the first two characters of a number

Tags: python-3.x, string

I've been googling around for what seems like forever and I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Plotly uses the print format styling for the x-axis tickmarks and my tick marks are about 7 characters in length and I want to reduce the amount of characters to 3

**Input**: 1200000k

**Desired Output**: 120

Below I have been messing around for what seems like forever but to no avail. I got the K removed so I'm wondering if anyone else understands how to do this with pythons print formatting nomenclature.

Here's the code down below, basically you pass the format of the tickmarks into the figure object.

```
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_tickformat = '3i%',
)
```

Here's some more clarification

[image]

Comment: Why demote it? Or can you give a reasoning. Literally, this makes no sense to me.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a solution but instead manipulated the data as Mithilesh suggested. I divided by 1000 and converted to integer as the easiest solution.

The formatting for plotly tick formats I have to admit is very lackluster in terms of documentation so anyone that is coming across this issue. I didn't resolve it after 2-3 hours of googling.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with string slicing. Try the below code.

```
k = "1200000k"
print(k[:3])
```

Comment: Can't pass that into plotly, it needs to be in this fstring format :(

Comment: So can't you control the data?

Comment: I can but I will be using this code frequently in many variations. I have a lot of data and doing this type of manipulation just seems very inefficient. It just seems absurd that this is complex to do in plotly/python to just get the first 3 characters of my string.

Comment: The documentation says about d3 like syntax but isn't clear on how to achieve it. https://plotly.com/python/reference/#layout-xaxis-tickformat
Modifying the input might be easy option.

Comment: Yeah plotly has made this very tough to accomplish...... when I went into d3 I was like wtf....

Comment: Exactly, don't know how d3 syntax can be used in python.

Comment: Yeah it's been around 1.5 hours trying to get the format for these. I'm starting to think that it's not possible.